# Что за метод isUserAMonkey()?

Tags: android, java

Зачем нужна функция [isUserAMonkey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey()) в Android SDK?

Comment: Мне тоже было дико интересно, что означает этот метод. Хотел задать точно такой же вопрос.

Comment: а сам автор знает ответ? или ему также просто интересно?

Comment: Пользователь может быть не только обезьяной, но еще и [козлом](https://geektimes.ru/post/241122/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ну, вот в общем и ответ на хабре: [инструменты функционального тестирования — Monkey и MonkeyRunner](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/131637/).

Comment: Ну это понятно... А вопрос то был: зачем нужен метод?

Comment: Судя по ответам, метод нужен для защиты от нежелательных действий. Как при стресс-тестах утилитой monkey, так и в случае, когда случайные события идут со стороны реального юзера. Например, когда несешь незаблокированный девайс в сумке, чтобы не совершались исходящие звонки или операции по оплате через банковскую карту, и т.д. Правда, не совсем понятно, каким именно образом программисты из гугл разграничивают макаку и человека...

Answer (score 6):

Есть предположение, что это как-то связано с методом автоматического тестирования интерфейса [Monkey Exerciser](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html). Например, что интерфейс корректо прошёл этот тест.

Comment: это просто прикол, пасхалка от разработчиков, как и метож wtf() =)

Comment: а прикол в том, что в любом случае метод возвращает false

**UPD** а если его перед этим потрясти - то true =)

Comment: хм... не подозревал

Comment: а попробуйте запустить monkeyrunner и посмотрите, что возвратит функция.

Comment: Поконкретнее ребята, поконкретнее... Тепло конечно, тепло

Answer (score 5):

с помощью MonkeyRunner можно написать питон скрипт который деплоит апк на девайс и затем блаблабла, а функция isUserAMonkey проверяет в коде установлено ли приложение таким образом или стандартно

Answer (score 5):

Есть еще одна интересная функция в android.os.UserManager:
public boolean isUserAGoat ()
Вот цитата из документации:

> Used to determine whether the user making this call is subject to
>   teleportations.
>
> As of LOLLIPOP, this method can now automatically identify goats using
>   advanced goat recognition technology.
>
> Returns
>
> ```
> Returns true if the user making this call is a goat.
> ```

По сути идет проверка стоит ли приложение "Симулятор козла". Вот такие шуточки программистов из Google